# How to ensure python code is terminated with vbscript when I am uploading vbscript to secure crt using pyautogui module?

Tags: python, pyautogui, secure-crt

I am trying to create an RPA based automation for running a vbscript in Secure CRT. In that, I am uploading vbscript to Secure CRT using pyautogui module. Now, my code ends even before all the logs download from vbscript is completed. How can I ensure that my python ends only after vbscript has run successfully and all the download is completed so that I can close secure CRT?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem in following ways:

1. Instead of using pyautogui module to upload vbscript on secureCRT, I used subprocess module as secureCRT has command line abilities to run vbscript:

   ```
   import subprocess
   RunVbs='\"'+ secureCRTPath +'\"' + ' /SCRIPT ' + '\"' + vbscriptPath + '\"'
   subprocess.Popen(RunVbs)
   ```
2. For ensuring that python script exits only after the vbscript has been run completely, I created a text file at the end of vbscript which was continuously scanned by python script. On finding the text file created by vbscript, python script would terminate:

   ```
   import time, os
   isVbsExecuted = False
   while isVbsExecuted == False:
       if os.path.exists('C:\VBSPath\OutputVBS.txt'):
           isVbsExecuted = True
       else:
           time.sleep(2)
   ```